# Спойлер при наведение которого отрываеться

Tags: jquery, javascript

У меня есть вот такой спойлер, но мне надо сделать чтоб он открывался не сверху вниз, а снизу вверх.
http://cssdeck.com/labs/wixjgejr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**jQuery** просто меняет css свойства **height** методом **slideDown**...

Поэтому нужно просто привязать позицию нижнего края

Например, вот [так](http://cssdeck.com/labs/coducckv)

- Текст перемещен в контейнер .spoiler:

  .spoiler {
    position: relative;
  }
- И спозиционирован по нижнему краю:

  position: absolute;
    bottom: -40px;

Добавил динамическое обновление позиции bottom:

```
      var b = -jQuery('.spoiler-text').outerHeight()-40;
      jQuery('.spoiler-text').css('bottom', b);
```

Comment: т.е. текст поставить снизу?

Comment: я отредактировал Ваш же fiddle. применена комбинация {position: absolute; bottom: 12px;} с {position: relative;} для контейнера

Comment: Есть одна проблема, если вставить много текста, то текст на который я навожу просто закрывает текстом снизу.

Comment: обновил фиддл